# Display coupon code on Product page. Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, product-page

I want to display the coupon code on the product page. In shopping cart price rules, I have applied coupons to a particular category. I want to display the coupon on every product page whose category id is specified in shopping cart price rules.

```
$current_sku=$_product->getSku(); // Sku you are looking for

$rules = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();

foreach ($rules as $rule) {
if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
    $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($rule->getId()); 

    $conditions = $rule->getConditions()->asArray();

    foreach( $conditions['conditions'] as $_conditions ):
        foreach( $_conditions['conditions'] as $_condition ):
            $string = explode(',', $_condition['value']);
            for ($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++) {
                $sku = trim($string[$i]);
                if ($sku==$current_sku) {
                        echo $rule->getCouponCode(); // Return coupon code that matches the sku condition
                }
            }
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
}
}
```

ref-
[Get Shopping cart rule coupon code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/get-shopping-cart-rule-coupon-code)

Answer (score 1):

ou can get applied shopping cart price rules on product page with below function

```
public function getShoppingCartRules($product) {
    $now = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
    $productData = new Varien_Object();
    $data = array(
        'product' => $product,
        'qty' => 1,
        'price' => $product->getFinalPrice(),
        'base_row_total' => $product->getFinalPrice()
    );
    $productData->setData($data);
    $allItems = new Varien_Object();
    $allItems->setAllItems(array($productData));
    $customerGroupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

    $ruleCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')
            ->addFieldToFilter('discount_amount', array("gt" => '0'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('coupon_type', array(1,2,3))
            ->setOrder('sort_order', 'DESC')
            ->addWebsiteGroupDateFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId(), $customerGroupId);
    $ruleCollection->getSelect()
            ->where('from_date is null or from_date <= ?', $now)
            ->where('to_date is null or to_date >= ?', $now);

    if ($ruleCollection->count()) {
            if ($rule->getActions()->validate($productData) && $rule->validate($allItems)) {
                $shoppingCartRules[] = $rule;
            }
        }
        return $shoppingCartRules;
    }
    return null;
}
```

where $product is product object already exist on product page.