# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, php-7

I'm trying to use this code I found here [Get Shopping cart rule coupon code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/get-shopping-cart-rule-coupon-code)
 (with alittle modifications) to get shopping cart rules:

```
<?php
$current_sku = $_product->getSku();
$rules       = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load();
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
        $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($rule->getId()); 
        $conditions = $rule->getConditions()->asArray();
        foreach( $conditions['conditions'] as $_conditions ):
            foreach( $_conditions['conditions'] as $_condition ):
                $string = explode(',', $_condition['value']);
                for ($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++) {
                    $sku = trim($string[$i]); ?>
<?php if ($sku === $current_sku): ?>
<div style="float:right;height:0">
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/free-gift.png',array('_secure'=>true)) ?>" style="max-width:140px;width:100%;height:auto;max-height:140px;position:relative;bottom:60px;left:10px" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
  <?php } endforeach;
        endforeach;
    }
}
 ?>
```

I'm using it on the Product Details page. The code works but I'm getting the following error on line 83 i.e.  `$conditions = $rule->getConditions()->asArray();`

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

It seems after searching Google I need to somehow check if the Array() has a value but I'm not sure how. Or maybe it suppose to always have a value?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$rules       = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/rule_collection')->load(); 
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        if ($rule->getIsActive()) {
            $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($rule->getId()); 
            $conditions = $rule->getConditions()->asArray();
            $conditions = (isset($conditions['conditions']) && $conditions['conditions']) ? $conditions['conditions'] : array();
            if(!empty($conditions)) {
                foreach($conditions as $_conditions ):
                    $_conditions = (isset($_conditions['conditions']) && $_conditions['conditions']) ? $_conditions['conditions'] : array();
                    if(!empty($_conditions)) { 
                        foreach($_conditions as $_condition ):
                        $string = explode(',', $_condition['value']);
                            for ($i=0; $i<count($string); $i++) {
                                $sku = trim($string[$i]); ?>
                                <?php if ($sku === $current_sku): ?>
                                <div style="float:right;height:0">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/free-gift.png',array('_secure'=>true)) ?>" style="max-width:140px;width:100%;height:auto;max-height:140px;position:relative;bottom:60px;left:10px" />
                                </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                  <?php 
                              } 
                        endforeach; 
                    }
                endforeach;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: No it didn't work.  It stop the error but the image also stop showing.